# Add Fragment on FrameLayout in Android

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, fragment

My Activity was extended to AppCompatActivity. I have successfully setup a drawer too. Now when i do transaction on Fragment basically it uses begintransaction. but i got this error message `Unreachable statement` on `android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();` and i also tried android.support.v4.app package it also say that this was desprecated.

In my drawer navigation `onClickListener`

i have this

`

```
mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                android.app.Fragment objFragment = null;

                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.dhome:
                        objFragment = new panel();
                        mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
                        return true;
                    case R.id.dsetting:

                        mCurrentSelectedPosition = 1;
                        return true;
                    case R.id.dlogout:

                        mCurrentSelectedPosition = 2;
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }

                // update the main content by replacing fragments
                if(objFragment != null) {
                    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
                            .commit();
                }

            }
        });`
```

in my layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
   >


    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#fff"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#d9d8d8"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.dhome:
            objFragment = new panel();
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
            break;
        case R.id.dsetting:
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = 1;
            break;
        case R.id.dlogout:
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = 2;
            break;
    }

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    if(objFragment != null) {
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                       .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
                       .commit();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Your previous code does not take in consideration how the user interacts with the `actionbar` (clicking any item), `return true;` will always be executed before reaching the *fragment transaction* code.

Comment: your answer was right :) ill accept it later. anyhow quick question.. in my home activity was extended to Fragment is it possible to return a layout of `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` with fully functioning google map?

Comment: I think that you need to do some configuration. I can't really remember how to setup maps with the *Google Maps API*.

Comment: Eventually i have that already. but its not a fragment type. its AppCompatActivity. but is that possible to setup a google map on Fragment?

Comment: Yes, I've actually seen that before.

Comment: Thanks mate ;) i figure that out.

Comment: GoogleMapFragment is typically implemented as a layout fragment. It could be possible to initialize it programatically, but from my experience is assumes it's on the screen more often more than it should, so it might be a pain implementing. However, that's a completely different topic; try it out and ask a question on site if you encounter a problem.

Comment: thanks @Luke maybe i should ask that later if i could not succeed.